# Creating proxy object to call methods of target asynchronously (splitting logic/render threads)

Tags: java, reflection, asynchronous

In my game design I'm trying to allow the logic and render threads to run as parallel as possible. Given this I need some way to push updates from the game logic into the rendering thread, and I'd like to find the cleanest way possible to do this.

Let me firstly apologize in that I'm just a hobbyist and I don't really know any design patterns or the right terminology for this, so if what I'm describing is known by a different name please let me know.

Assume that I have an object which looks something like this, that is continually accessed by the rendering thread:

```
public class Renderable {
   void functionA(int foo)          { ... }
   void functionB(int foo, int bar) { ... }
   void functionC()                 { ... }
}
```

I need to call `functionA` , `functionB`, and `functionC` at random points during my logic thread, but because the objects are in different threads I can't directly touch Renderable without concurrency problems. What I really want to do is just create a proxy object `RenderableProxy` with the same interface as `Renderable`, which will store all calls to it, and then forward the calls to `Renderable` during a synchronization window when I have aligned the threads.

The object will look something like this:

```
public class RenderableProxy {
    Renderable target;

    void functionA(int foo)            { ? }
    void functionB(int foo, int bar)   { ? }
    void functionC()                   { ? }

    void execute()   {
        foreach( called_function )
           target.???      
    }             
}
```

Now I trust that I could probably implement this, if I created some struct which held information like an enum representing the function, and stored the parameters, and then just hold this all until I call `execute`.

But what really annoys me about this is that every time I make an update to `Renderable` interface, I have to come back to `RenderableProxy` and modify the interface to match, and modify `execute` to handle the changes. This feels really messy to me and I feel like there might be a language feature to somehow handle this, such that anytime I change Renderable interface, I don't have to rewrite `RenderableProxy` to handle the new function.

Is there such a magical feature that will allow me to achieve my goal, without constantly trying to keep interfaces of two different objects (object and its proxy) in sync? I know java has some reflection features, though I'm a bit afraid to touch that as I'm worried about the performance implications of performing reflection lookup a few thousand times per second in a 60Hz game.

Comment: if you call setA(1);setA(2); is this equivalent to setA(2) only? If so, you need not to save all calls to setA and then run foreach. If not, then setA is a misleading name, call it addA or smth.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov The intention is that every function called on the proxy also gets called on the real object during the synchronization period. I haven't fully fleshed out the interface yet but it could also have functions that aren't strictly setters, like "incrementA". The rule just boils down to: proxy intercepts the function call, and calls the exact same function on the target at a later time. Edited example to remove some ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Proxy class (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) to achieve this.
See a good tutorial of how to use it here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp08305/index.html.
Basically you need RenderableProxy to implement InvocationHandler.
 - In the invoke() method of RenderableProxy store the methods to be invoked in-memory
 - add a new executeAll() method to RenderableProxy which executes all the stored method invocations
 - Invoke the executeAll() method at will.

Comment: Thank you, that does look interesting and something like what I'm looking for. I'm slightly concerned about the perf implications of performing reflection hundreds/thousands of time per second (I'm programming for mobile device), but it may be worth a try if it's the best option.